# Trouble with attribute 'cli' in a fresh Flask install

Tags: python, flask, pip

To run the flask examples off the repo, I clone the latest stable, create a virtual environment, activate it, pip install flask, and try to run flaskr.py. The following script goes through this sequence.

```
#!/bin/bash

NEWROOT=${HOME}/flask
mkdir $NEWROOT
git clone https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git $NEWROOT/repo
virtualenv $NEWROOT/venv

source $NEWROOT/venv/bin/activate
pip install flask
cd $NEWROOT/repo/examples/flaskr/
python flaskr.py
```

The last line fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskr.py", line 48, in <module>
    @app.cli.command('initdb')
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'cli'
```

What am I missing?

In this context I also do not understand: if I do not run "pip install flask", I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
ImportError: No module named flask
```

If I do, I get the earlier error. Hence it appears that "pip install flask" did indeed install flask, but I don't see flask (not even as a symlink) in the newly created ${HOME}/flask/venv. Where was flask installed?

Python 2.7.10 (from MacPorts); pip 1.5.6; OS X 10.9.5

Comment: run `locate flask.py` its probably in your /usr/lib/python27/dist-packages folder

Comment: you could also open python and do `import flask;print flask.__file__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.cli` is a feature in the v1.0 branch of flask, not in the main 0.10 branch which is the stable branch you get by default from pip. Either install v1.0 with pip, or delete that part of the code.

Comment: Replacing 'pip install flask' with 'pip install https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tarball/master' in the bash sequence only partially works. There is no longer a cli-related error, but no server is launched. 'python flaskr.py' simply returns to the command-line.